# How to change colour of object, not world

Tags: materials, objects

new to blender here. Been trying to follow tutorials on youtube to get myself started but was unable to figure out this issue:

I want to change the colour of the material selected (the wheel), however, I only seem to be able to toggle the setting for world colour instead. How can I change the colour setting to toggle for material selected instead? Is anyone able to help?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome, erri.

You're not trying to change the material, you're changing the world instead.

Use the Material panel to make the changes to the material.

See the image below.

[image]

Comment: OHhhh cool, many thanks haha I clearly wasn't looking at the icons clearly on the youtube video I was following xD

Answer (score 0):

You haven't selected the object (as pointed out in the comments, he did select the object). First of all select the object.
Second, press "material" on the bar

[image: Material bar]

Then, press "new material"

[image]

Comment: Hi. You can see in the screenshot that the selected object (the wheel) has an orange outline.